# SQL SELECT - GROUP BY

Tags: sql, select, group-by, visual-foxpro

Very much starting with SQL.

I am trying to gather data from a couple of tables to produce a summary where the values from the first table are grouped by a field, Repcode, and totalled.  And in the resultant cursor there is to be a description taken from the second table, by looking up on the Repcode field.

This is a much simplified test program

```
CREATE CURSOR Nomtot (tcode C(4), tRepcode C(2), tBalance N(9,2))
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("A001", "12", 123.45)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("B003", "17", 555.45)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("B006", "19", 666.00)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("E008", "12", 810.00)

CREATE CURSOR RepLook (tRepcode C(2), tDesc C(30))
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("12", "Materials")
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("17", "Carriage")
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("19", "Dividends")

SELECT a.tRepcode, SUM(a.tBalance) AS tBalance, b.tDesc ;
  FROM Nomtot a, Replook b ;
  GROUP BY a.tRepcode ;
  WHERE a.tRepcode = b.tRepcode ;
  INTO CURSOR cResult
```

This however produces an error : SQL GROUP BY command is missing or invalid.
If I then change the  statement to GROUP BY a.tRepcode, b.tDesc ;
   . . . the program produces the required result.
Why is this second clause necessary?  Am I doing this correctly

Grateful for guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: In the way you have it written, you will need to group by `b.tDesc` as well.  This is because you must group by all non-aggregate columns.

Answer (score 2):

add the group by for all the columns not involved in aggreagation function
and move the where before the group by

```
SELECT a.tRepcode, SUM(a.tBalance) AS tBalance, b.tDesc 
FROM Nomtot a, Replook b 
WHERE a.tRepcode = b.tRepcode 
GROUP BY a.tRepcode, b.tDesc
```

or using the the current join style  (as ssuggested  by YogeshSharma)

```
SELECT a.tRepcode, SUM(a.tBalance) AS tBalance, b.tDesc 
FROM Nomtot a
INNER JOIN  Replook b ON a.tRepcode = b.tRepcode 
GROUP BY a.tRepcode, b.tDesc
```

Comment: Why you referring the old style of `JOIN` syntax ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma  .. correct  ..I had only copied the OP code  .. answer  updated  with current join style too

Comment: @YogeshSharma  thanks for correct editing .. upvote .. somewhere

Comment: @scaisEdge question is tagged VFP. It would be wrong IF you remove the ;. Also moving the where before group by would make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is that SQL will need to aggregate on all colomns that arent a calculation.

In other language like SAS it wouldnt be required but your calculation would be based only on what the group by has. In other words your SUM(a.tBalance) would have the same value for all b.tDesc. In your case it may be a one to one match and it wouldnt matter but in some other case your b.Table could have multiple matched values and should have different sums....
Another way to do it without having to include the b.tDesc in group by :
select a.*, b.tDesc 
from (
SELECT a.tRepcode, SUM(a.tBalance) AS tBalance 
  FROM Nomtot) a
inner join Replook b
on a.tRepcode = b.tRepcode ;

Comment: Thank you very much, Wired.  I can see that in my original code, if tRepcode were not unique (in fact it is) in the Replook, table, then there would have been a problem in determining which tDesc value to take from the RepLook table.  As Cetin says, I need to include all non-aggregated columns in the 'GROUP BY' clause.  I will also check out your 2-level SELECT.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include all non-aggregate columns in group by. That is the reason. A better way of writing that query would be:

```
CREATE CURSOR Nomtot (tcode C(4), tRepcode C(2), tBalance N(9,2))
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("A001", "12", 123.45)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("B003", "17", 555.45)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("B006", "19", 666.00)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("E008", "12", 810.00)

CREATE CURSOR RepLook (tRepcode C(2), tDesc C(30))
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("12", "Materials")
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("17", "Carriage")
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("19", "Dividends")

SELECT a.tRepcode, a.tBalance, b.tDesc ;
  FROM ;
  (select tRepCode, sum(tBalance) as tBalance ;
   from nomtot ;
   group by tRepCode ) a ;
  inner join Replook b on a.tRepcode = b.tRepcode ;
  INTO CURSOR cResult ;
  nofilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using vfp 8 or 9 then all you have to do is add this one line of code to the top of your program.

```
SET ENGINEBEHAVIOR 70
```

using your example.

```
SET ENGINEBEHAVIOR 70

CREATE CURSOR Nomtot (tcode C(4), tRepcode C(2), tBalance N(9,2))
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("A001", "12", 123.45)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("B003", "17", 555.45)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("B006", "19", 666.00)
INSERT INTO nomtot (tCode, tRepcode, tBalance) VALUES ("E008", "12", 810.00)

CREATE CURSOR RepLook (tRepcode C(2), tDesc C(30))
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("12", "Materials")
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("17", "Carriage")
INSERT INTO Replook(tRepcode, tDesc) VALUES ("19", "Dividends")

SELECT a.tRepcode, SUM(a.tBalance) AS tBalance, b.tDesc ;
  FROM Nomtot a, Replook b ;
  GROUP BY a.tRepcode ;
  WHERE a.tRepcode = b.tRepcode ;
  INTO CURSOR cResult
```

of course you could rewrite the query the correct way but this works all the same.

Comment: Using SET ENGINEBEHAVIOR 70 is a bad habit to get into. The reason it was changed is that there are cases where the old behavior gives you the wrong answer. Better to write the query so it meets the new rules.

Comment: I guess I have bad habits then.  Been working in vFP daily for 20 years.  I have never had an issue with my queries.   Luck I guess. I understand why we write queries the "correct way" and have to do it in Mysql/Isieries and other platforms.  But the reason I still use vFP 10 years outside of it being supported is because its the quickest tool I have to quickly write code to handle modelerate sized data (oh, that 2GB).  If I have to start learning new, "correct" ways of doing things, vFP will quickly start to look and feel as old as it actually is.

Comment: The easiest way to see a problem with the old form is with any query that uses MIN() or MAX().

Answer (score 0):

Cetin Basoz's answer is right and it should be accepted as answer but I want to add one more thing that you can use MAX() or MIN() function with not aggregated fields like this

```
SELECT MAX(a.tRepcode) AS tRepcode, SUM(a.tBalance) AS tBalance, MAX(b.tDesc) AS tDesc ;
  FROM Nomtot a, Replook b ;
  GROUP BY a.tRepcode ;
  WHERE a.tRepcode = b.tRepcode ;
  INTO CURSOR cResult
```